# MongoDB 3.0.0: Set quota PER database, not for all databases?

Tags: mongodb

Using the maxFilesPerDB and smallFiles options of MongoDB, I've got it so that each database is capped at 256 MB.  What do I do when a particular user has a special circumstance which requires more space than that?  Is my only option really to increase the quota for ALL databases?

Our general policy will be to take a hard stance and say "sorry, that's all you get," but having been here for a few years, I know there's always special scenarios that come up which require manual intervention for reasons, sometimes by people higher than me, which I can't deny.  Is my only option really to increase the quota for all databases?